# In spring mvc, is it possible to restrict validating a field if an error has caught

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and making use of `Spring JSR-303` annotation to validate the fields. So lets suppose if an error has occurred for a field it should stop verifying other used annotation for this same field. Given below is the snippet. Sorry for the bad formatting.
Given below is my Snippet

**User.java**

```
public class User 
{
    @Pattern(regexp="^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$",message="Not a well defiened format")
    @NotBlank
    String email;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }}
```

if email is left blank then it should **not check the pattern** and should only display `"cannot be left blank"`.Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you only asking in context with email.

Comment: yeah..cant it will be done with pattern also.

Comment: yeah i am asking only for email...isn't it possible with @pattern annotation as it is my dependency

Answer (score 0):

Just try

- `@Email` annotation for email validation
- `@NotEmpty` annotation instead of `@NotBlank`

for example:

```
@NotEmpty
@Email
private String email;
```

[Read more...](http://codetutr.com/2013/05/28/spring-mvc-form-validation/)

Comment: Is `@NotEmpty`  and  `@NotNull` does the similar work?

Comment: His question is not particularly about email.